# What is an appropriate forum for asking off-topic, story-based questions?

Tags: tools, resources, feedback

I'm looking for a good website/blog/forum for posting questions that are technically off-topic for this website. I am looking for something that would allow me to post about story-based things, such as, "Would it makes sense for a character to X if he is in X situation?"

Stack Exchange is more of a direct question-answer site, for example, "What is a short story?" is something you could ask here but **I'm looking for a place to post questions about things in my story/get feedback/give feedback.**

Comment: I don't understand what 'story based questions' are.

Comment: Dylan, asking for lists of stuff is off topic here but I think this can be edited to be okay. But in the meantime, can you clarify what you mean by story-based questions? Do you just mean a site that specializes in fiction?

Comment: Have rephrased the question but please make further edits!

Comment: @Lew gave me exactly what I was looking for so I am closing the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Critique Circle](http://www.critiquecircle.com/default.asp)

[Scribophile](http://www.scribophile.com/)

I am sure there are others, but they are all based on the same principle: to get critique, one should give critique first (it is a good practice too, helps to see flaws in your own work), it's only fair.

If you just want to chat about writing in general, they do have forums.